# Change virtual host directory based on IP address

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible in Apache to change the Directory parameter based on the users IP address (i.e. in htaccess)? The logic is that if I'm building a test site it would be great to see it in a test mode for my IP but keep it live and unaffected for public users. That way effectively one domain can appear differently without changing the site root path. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 virtual hosts, that way you can set a different document root and path for the hostnames. You can restrict acces to your test environment using htpasswd, or put your ip adres in your test virtualhost on the allowfrom list and deny acces to everyone else.
This way you can create urls like test.domain.com and domain.com resolving to the correct environment.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the full domain - only the subdomain so I can't create more subdomains. Is there no other way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, if your test environment code is inside your live application you should be able to call urls like domain.com/index.php (live) and domain.com/test/index.php (test). Just make sure you have your anchors pointing to the right environment.